# Stack in the structure of echoing multiple looping

Tags: php, html, css

This is my php code for echoing contents from database.

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
$results = $mysqli->query
("SELECT transaction_id FROM orders_list WHERE customer_name = 'Klaudia' ORDER BY id LIMIT 100");           
if ($results) {
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
        echo '<div id="thisklop">';
        echo '<ul class="ulung">Id_cart';           
        echo '<li>'.$obj->transaction_id.'</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
                $thisthat=$obj->transaction_id;         
                $otherresults = $mysqli->query
                            ("SELECT transaction_id, items, quantity, one_product_price FROM orders_history
                              WHERE transaction_id = '$thisthat'");         
                if ($otherresults) {
                    while($obj = $otherresults->fetch_object()) {
                        echo '<div>';
                        echo '<ul class="ulung">Products';
                        echo '<li>'.$obj->items.'</li>';
                        echo '</ul>';
                        echo '</div><br>';

                        echo '<div>';
                        echo '<ul class="ulung">Quantity';
                        echo '<li>'.$obj->quantity.'</li>';
                        echo '</ul>';
                        echo '</div><br>';

                        echo '<div>';
                        echo '<ul class="ulung">Invoices';
                        echo '<li>'.$obj->one_product_price.'</li>';
                        echo '</ul>';
                        echo '</div><br>';
                    }
                }                                       
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

What I want the result is like this:

**[UPDATE TABLE]**

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id_cart         products        quantity       invoices     status
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
                 this               2             $20        
  0001           that               1             $20        pending
                 those              2             $20        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 Total Invoices:  $60   
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------

                 this               2             $20        
  0002           that               1             $20        approved
                 those              2             $20        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 Total Invoices:  $60
```

From the table above, the id_cart is in looping, and then inside the id_cart there are also content which are in looping.

I am stuck on the structure I am echoing it. The structure is in a mess

[image]

Comment: You mean stuck, not stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get all data in one query (faster) and then collect your data in an array first. Finally, construct the output according to the array:

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
$results = $mysqli->query
("
    SELECT  DISTINCT    orders_history.transaction_id,
                        orders_history.items,
                        orders_history.quantity,
                        orders_history.one_product_price
    FROM                orders_history, orders_list
    WHERE               orders_history.transaction_id = orders_list.transaction_id
    AND                 orders_list.customer_name = 'Klaudia'"

);

$orders = array();     
$html = '';     
if ($results) {
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
        $orders[$obj->transaction_id][$obj->items] = array('quantity' => $obj->quantity, 'invoices' => $obj->one_product_price);
    }

        $html .= '<table><tr>';
        $html .= '<th>id_cart</th>';
        $html .= '<th>products</th>';
        $html .= '<th>quantity</th>';
        $html .= '<th>invoices</th></tr>';
        foreach ($orders AS $order_id => $order) {
            $html .= '<tr><td rowspan="' . count($order) . '">' . $order_id . '</td>';
            $row = 1;
            foreach ($order AS $item => $data) {
                if ($row > 1) { $html .= '</tr><tr>'; }
                $html .= '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
                $html .= '<td>' . $data['quantity'] . '</td>';
                $html .= '<td>' . $data['invoices'] . '</td>';
/* INSERTED CODE FOR STATUS */
                if ($row == 1) {
                  $html .= '<tr><td rowspan="' . count($order) . '">' . $status . '</td>';
                }
/* END OF INSERTION */
                $row++;
            }
            $html .= '</tr>';
        }
        $html .= '</table>';
    } 
    echo $html;
    ?>
```

*Note: This is written untested out of my head, might have some errors but the main path should be clear.*

Comment: Did you get any error messages? Can you post the result of `var_dump($results)` (insert just before the `$orders = array();` line)?

Comment: it just printed `bool(false)`

Comment: When I changed it to `print_r ($results);` it doesn't show anything   too.

Comment: I just solved it. But I need more from there. I want to calculate the total price and then show it at the bottom of the invoices(what I need is only how to put it in the table, for the data I can get it from another row of column on the table). For example: `Total = 60.000` for each id_cart. _Look at my update table above in the question_

Comment: And also I want each result of `id_cart` is wrapped so that I can set a border style on each seperated blocks, which will look the same as the example above. Help.

Comment: Just add another row just after `$html .= '</tr>';` to add the total which you need to calculate inside the foreach order loop. As for the border styling, I am not sure what you mean, you have a lot of table cells now which you can style in any way you want. You can even add classes and ids in the code to target specific cells.

Comment: Okay. thanks for you help. Hope that you can help me again next time.

Comment: please see my update table in the question above. Now I want the position of status is also similar to the position of id_cart. How to position it?